# The network animator malfunctioning

Tags: networking, ns2, animator

I'm working on project called heterogeneous resource allocation using Network simulator 2.35...and i'm new to this simulator,the coding part is alright but i'm really troubled as i'm not getting to observe all the transmission of nodes properly as the animator is appearing in a very small window and can't even maximize it tried all the basics like alt + enter and going into performance settings even some advanced setting too...really stuck up here!!!, can't understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

---

Your issues may be caused by a faulty 'tk8' install ? Or ?

Please try out a well tested 'nam' binary package ...
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn't-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2

! You may have to delete your current 'nam', for a new one to work.
Delete : ns-allinone-2.35/nam-1.15/. And /usr/bin/nam ( If present.)

---